# Invalid credential date. Date is not the same as X-Amz-Date

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm using a signing key generated on 05-13-2019 and the scope as "20190513/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request". My requests are getting rejected with a "The authorization header is malformed; Invalid credential date. Date is not the same as X-Amz-Date" error. If I change the signing key by using the current date and change the scope using the current date (05-14-2019), my request is being served. According to the documentation, signing key should be valid for up to 7 days. Can anyone help me understand why this issue is happening?

Answer (score 1):

The signing key *is* valid for 7 days, but can only be used on requests dated from midnight to midnight on the date associated with the signing key -- that is, the credential scope must match `X-Amz-Date`.

The 7 day validity concept comes from the maximum value of `X-Amz-Expires`, which is 604800 (7 days).  Values larger than this can't be used because the expiration time of the signature would extend past the lifetime of the signing key.

Comment: Could you explain this more detailed? I have the same issue with and previously I was able to use the scope for I week

Comment: @KirillVoronin Exactly my issue. I was able to use the same scope for one week.